# Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. won't continue

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I am trying to open a pdf to get the number of pages. I am using PyPDF2.

Here is my code:

```
def pdfPageReader(file_name):
    try:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file_name, strict=True)
        number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
        print(f"{file_name} = {number_of_pages}")
        return number_of_pages
    except:
        return "1"
```

But then i run into this error:

> PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1736]

I tried to use strict=True and strict=False, When it is True, it displays this message, and nothing, I waited for 30minutes, but nothing happened. When it is False, it just display nothing, and that's it, just do nothing, if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on the terminal (cmd, windows 10) then it cancel that open and continues (I run this in a batch of pdf files). Only 1 in the batch got this problem.

My questions are, how do I fix this, or how do I skip this, or how can I cancel this and move on with the other pdf files?

Answer (score 31):

If somebody had a similar problem and it even crashed the program with this error message

File "C:\Programy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1604, in getObject
% (indirectReference.idnum, indirectReference.generation, idnum, generation))
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Expected object ID (14 0) does not match actual (13 0); xref table not zero-indexed.

It helped me to add the strict argument equal to False for my pdf reader

```py
pdf_reader = PdfReader(input_file, strict=False)
```

Comment: This worked for me but it might be interesting to know why.

Comment: interesting or tedious?

Answer (score 9):

For anybody else who may be running into this problem, and found that `strict=False` didn't help, I was able to solve the problem by just **re-saving a new copy of the file in Adobe Acrobat Reader**.  I just opened the PDF file inside an actual copy of Adobe Acrobat Reader (the plain ol' free version on Windows), did a "Save as...", and gave the file a new name. Then I ran my script again using the newly saved copy of my PDF file.

Apparently, the PDF file I was using, which was generated directly from my scanner, was somehow corrupt, even though I could open and view it just fine in Reader. Making a duplicate copy of the file via re-saving in Acrobat Reader somehow seemed to correct whatever was missing.

Comment: Good! It worked for me opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat, then Save as.... It passed from 900kb to 500kb. Now it works.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and looked for a way to skip it. I am not a programmer but looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/warnings.html) about warnings there is a piece of code that helps you avoid such hindrance.

Although I wouldn't recomend this as a solution, the piece of code that I used for my purpose is (just copied and pasted it from doc on link)

```
import sys

if not sys.warnoptions:
    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

Comment: this way you are not solving the issue, just hiding it to not see. I just want you to understand

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me when the file was created in a printer / scanner combo that generates PDFs. I could read in the PDF with only a warning though so I read it in, and then rewrote it as a new file. I could append that new one.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger, PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("scanner_generated.pdf", strict=False)
writer = PdfWriter()

for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)

with open("fixedPDF.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)

merger = PdfMerger()
merger.append("fixedPDF.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and the solutions did help but didn't solve the problem completely, at least the one setting strict=False & resaving the document using Acrobat reader.
Anyway, I still got a stream error, but I was able to fix it after using an PDF online repair. I used [sejda.com](https://www.sejda.com/de/repair-pdf) but please be aware that you are uploading your PDF on some website, so make sure there is nothing sensible in there.