# Extract specific pages of PDF and save it with Python

Tags: python, pdf, extract, pypdf

I have some sources and tried to code which extract some pages and create pdf files.
I have a list which looks like this

```
information = [(filename1,startpage1,endpage1), (filename2, startpage2, endpage2), ...,(filename19,startpage19,endpage19)].
```

This is my code.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

reader = PdfFileReader("example.pdf")

for page in range(reader.getNumPages() - 1):
    writer = PdfFileWriter()
    start = information[page][1]
    end = information[page][2]
    while start < end:
        writer.addPage(reader.getPage(start))
        start += 1
        output_filename = "{}_{}_page_{}.pdf".format(
            information[page][0], information[page][1], information[page][2]
        )
    with open(output_filename, "wb") as out:
        writer.write(out)
```

But the output is weird.. some has nothing inside and some has just one page in it. How can I correct this?

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated since 2022. Use pypdf.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. it was the equal sign (start<=end).

```
for page in range(len(information)):
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    start = information[page][1]
    end = information[page][2]
    while start<=end:
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(start-1))
        start+=1
    if not os.path.exists(savepath):
        os.makedirs(savepath)
    output_filename = '{}_{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(information[page][0],information[page][1], information[page][2])
    with open(output_filename,'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)
```

Comment: I have been looking for something like this for hours. Thanks SSS.

Answer (score 8):

Full code and I modified SSS' answer to be portable, flexible, and concurrent with multiple source pdfs.
I couldn't test the performance difference between ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor, but I assumed that the extraction process is bounded by the reading and writing of PDFs rather than by getting the page and add_page.

```py
import concurrent.futures
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
from pathlib import Path

from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader


def pdf_extract(pdf, segments, together=False):
    """
    pdf: str | Path
    segments: [(start, end), {'start': int, 'end': int}]
    """
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    with open(pdf, 'rb') as read_stream:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(read_stream)
        pdf_writer_segment = PdfWriter()
        for segment in segments:
            # support {'start': 3, 'end': 3} or (start, end)
            try:
                start_page, end_page = segment['start'], segment['end']
            except TypeError:
                start_page, end_page = segment
            for page_num in range(start_page - 1, end_page):
                if together:
                    pdf_writer.add_page(pdf_reader.pages[page_num])
                else:
                    pdf_writer_segment.add_page(pdf_reader.pages[page_num])
            p = Path(pdf)
            if not together:
                ouput = p.parent / p.with_stem(f'{p.stem}_pages_{start_page}-{end_page}')
                with open(ouput, 'wb') as out:
                    pdf_writer_segment.write(out)
    if together:
        ouput = p.parent / p.with_stem(f'{p.stem}_extracted')
        with open(ouput, 'wb') as out:
            pdf_writer.write(out)


def __pdf_extract(pair):
    return pdf_extract(*pair)


def pdf_extract_batch(pdfs, workers=20):
    """
    pdfs = {pdf_name: [(1, 1), ...], ...}
    """
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        executor.map(__pdf_extract, pdfs.items())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    pdf_name = r"C:\Users\maste\Documents\long.pdf"
    segments = [(1, 1), {'start': 3, 'end': 5}]
    # Single
    pdf_extract(pdf_name, segments)
    # Batched (Concurrent)
    pdfs = {pdf_name: segments}
    # pdf_extract_batch(pdfs)
```

Comment: If you encounter a `xref table not zero-indexed`, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939085/xref-table-not-zero-indexed-id-numbers-for-objects-will-be-corrected-wont-con) question.

Comment: `p.with_stem` - "not available". You can use the following function:
```def change_stem(fn, new_stem):
    stem = fn.split("/")[-1];
    ext = stem.split(".")[-1];
    stem_noext = stem[0:-len(ext)-1];
    return stem_noext+new_stem+"."+ext;
```

Answer (score 3):

The older answers are good, but there have been some changes after PyPDF version 3.0.0. Here's an updated alternative (basically the reader and writer classes were renamed, and `getPage()` is now `pages[]`). If you only need one fragment simply remove the first loop.

Important note: this works without changes with pypdf, since PyPDF2 seems deprecated.

```
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter


pdf_reader = PdfReader(source_pdf_file_path)
pages = [(1, 3), (2, 6)]
for page_indices in pages:
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()  # we want to reset this when starting a new pdf
    for idx in range(page_indices[0] - 1, page_indices[1]):
        pdf_writer.add_page(pdf_reader.pages[idx])
    output_filename = f"{out_folder}/{source_pdf_file_path.stem}_{page_indices[0]}.pdf"
    with open(output_filename, "wb") as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)
```

Comment: Previous answers use deprecated method. This answer is inline with the latest version of PyPdf2.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Comment: Changed the answer to reflect this. It's great that the solution worked without any changes in pypdf :)

Answer (score 0):

my quick solution :

```
    from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
    pdf_file_path = 'file.pdf'
    file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '')

    pdf = PdfReader(pdf_file_path)
    print('ca passe avant le decoupage')
    pages = [0, 2, 4] # page 1, 3, 5
    pdfWriter = PdfWriter()

    for page_num in pages:
        pdfWriter.add_page(pdf.pages[page_num])

    with open('{0}_subset.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
        pdfWriter.write(f)
        f.close()
```

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Comment: Not sure about the librarys, just used it for my app and does the job very well

Comment: Yes, deprecated doesn't mean broken. It just means that it will not receive any further updates. I'm the maintainer of both libraries. I deprecated PyPDF2 after merging the updates to pypdf