# Extract specific page from multiple pdfs in python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to extract the 6th page from each pdf in a folder in my directory and place each page in a different folder with new file names.
I used the following source: [Extract specific pages of PDF and save it with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567750/extract-specific-pages-of-pdf-and-save-it-with-python) and [Extract pdf](https://learndataanalysis.org/how-to-extract-pdf-pages-and-save-as-a-separate-pdf-file-using-python/) for most of my code but I get an error that the file is a string

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from pathlib import Path
import glob
file_path = 'mypath\*pdf'
new_filepath='mynewfile_path'
file_path=glob.glob(file_path)
i=1
for file in file_path:   
   input_pdf = PdfFileReader(file)
   first_page = input_pdf.getPage(5)
   pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
   i=str(i)  
   with open(i+ subset.pdf'.format(new_filepath), 'wb') as f:
       pdf_writer.write(f)
       f.close()
  i=int(i)
  i+=1
```

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: This would be better handled by a shell script or batch file running standalone tools like `cpdf` and `pdftk`.  You don't really need Python for this.

Comment: You have not added your page to the `pdf_writer`.  And, of course, the line attempting to open the new file has two or three errors.  What, exactly, do you want the output file names to be?

Comment: file names to be 1subset.pdf, 2subset.pdf, etc.